# Lock form on expiration date

Tags: php, date, time

An event is created on a set date and starting time. You can signup for this event by using a checkbox form. This form must lock when there's exactly 7 days left before the event starts.

```
<?php if ($tentamenweek['Week'] > $date) {
    echo "Executes lock form script";
}
    else {
        echo "Executes open form script";
    }

?>
```

This code, if I'm right, locks the form when the scheduled event passes today's date. It needs to lock the form 7 days before the event starts. So I'm trying to figure out how to calculate how much time there's left towards the event and lock the form if it reaches 7 days before the event starts.

Comment: so, what's wrong with what you're using now?

Comment: This code locks the form when the scheduled event passes today's date. It needs to lock the form 7 days before the event starts. So I'm trying to figure out how to calculate how much time there's left towards the event and lock the form if it reaches 7 days before the event starts.

p.s. i'm a first year IT student, 5 weeks into my first year and my php knowledge currently exists out of php codecademy courses. They're throwing us in at the deep end but I'm really eager to learn.

Comment: Can you make this comment a part of your question? You should describe the behavior you expect verses the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Edited the question.

Comment: Its a little difficult to guess an answer as you have not mentioned what data is in either `$tentamenweek['Week']` or `$date`

Comment: Worst part is, I'm not even sure myself. Like I said before our tutor is throwing us in the deep to test our problem solving abilities. He basically gave us an completed website/database and said "write some new features using existing code" whilst our php knowledge currently exists out of a couple of codecademy courses. I think in order for me to solve this problem I need to go back to basics by creating a new page and see how I can extract data from a database. After that I should learn how to compare this data with other data. You recon this is the way to go?

Comment: Just add a `print_r($tentamenweek);` and `echo `$date`

Comment: tentamenweek returns 'Array ( [Week] => 42 )' and $date returns an error 'Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string' in case you were still interested. So if I want to compare tentamenweek's date to the current date I first need to convert the week to day?

Answer (score 0):

Use the strtotime function

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))`

This will return 7 days before the current date

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can not tell you if this is what I need due to my php and mysql knowledge at this point in time being so little. In order to solve my problem I need to go back to basics and start working my way up to completing my feature from there.